# C# filter XML data to include hyperlinks

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net

I am currently using a filter on my homepage that allows you to select a category from a drop down and then by hitting search displays the Clients name and Logo.

I used the tutorial explained on the following link:

http://www.dbtutorials.com/retrieve/linq-to-xml-cs.aspx

At the moment though I manually enter the hyperlink in the XML like so:

```
<ClientName><![CDATA[<a href='category-list.aspx?cat=exampleclient'>Example Client</a>]]></ClientName>
```

This does show the link correctly but think its a bit messy.

I would prefer it so it looked like:

```
<ClientName>Example Client</ClientName>
```

In the c# I have tried to make the hyperlink work but it hasn't quite worked. This is before the edit which picks up the XML information:

```
litXMLData.Text = litXMLData.Text + person.ClientLogo + "<br />";                  
litXMLData.Text = litXMLData.Text + person.ClientName;
```

And when I have tried to update it:

```
litXMLData.Text = "<a href='category-list.aspx?cat=" + litXMLData.Text + person.ClientName + ""'>" + person.ClientName + "</a>";
```

and it comes up with the following error:

CS1010: Newline in constant

So I am a little stuck... Any ideas?

Below is all the C# code if it helps before my update above:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(!IsPostBack)
loadDDL();
}

protected void loadDDL()
{
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Server.MapPath("XML/homepage-results.xml"));
XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("Persons/Person");

//Below code modified by Chris so duplicated categories are not displayed ;

foreach(XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    ListItem newItem = new ListItem(node.SelectSingleNode("category").InnerText);

    if (!ddlcategory.Items.Contains(newItem))
    {
        ddlcategory.Items.Add(newItem);
    }
}
}

//End of modification ;

protected void butGetXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("XML/homepage-results.xml"));

var persons = from person in xmlDoc.Descendants("Person")
select new
{
ClientLogo = person.Element("ClientLogo").Value,
category = person.Element("category").Value,
ClientName = person.Element("ClientName").Value,
};

litXMLData.Text = "";
foreach (var person in persons)
{
litXMLData.Text = litXMLData.Text + "" + person.ClientLogo + "<br />";
//Removed category name displaying on the screen - litXMLData.Text = litXMLData.Text + "Category: " + person.category + "<br />";     
litXMLData.Text = litXMLData.Text + "" + person.ClientName + "<br /><br />";
}

if (litXMLData.Text == "")
litXMLData.Text = "No Results.";
}

protected void butFilterXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("XML/homepage-results.xml"));

var persons = from person in xmlDoc.Descendants("Person")
where person.Element("category").Value == ddlcategory.SelectedItem.ToString()
select new
{
ClientLogo = person.Element("ClientLogo").Value,
category = person.Element("category").Value,
ClientName = person.Element("ClientName").Value,
};

litXMLData.Text = "";
foreach (var person in persons)
{

litXMLData.Text = litXMLData.Text + person.ClientLogo + "<br />";                   
litXMLData.Text = litXMLData.Text  + person.ClientName + "<br /><br />";

}

if (litXMLData.Text == "")
litXMLData.Text = "No Results.";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some modification I have now entered the following string format:

So from:

```
litXMLData.Text = litXMLData.Text + person.ClientLogo + "<br />";                  
litXMLData.Text = litXMLData.Text + person.ClientName;
```

to:

```
foreach (var person in persons)
{
    topRow = string.Format(@"{0} <td>{1}</td>", topRow, person.ClientLogo);
    bottomRow = string.Format(@"{0} <td><img src='images/arrow.jpg'  align='texttop'><a href='category-list.aspx?cat={2}'>{1}</a></td>", bottomRow, person.ClientName, person.CategoryLink);
}

topRow = string.Format(@"{0} </tr>", topRow);
bottomRow = string.Format(@"{0} </tr>", bottomRow);

litXMLData.Text = string.Format(@"{0}{1}", topRow, bottomRow);

if (litXMLData.Text == "")
litXMLData.Text = "No Results.";
}
}
```

So now the XML can now be:

```
<Person>
<ClientLogo><![CDATA[<img src='images/clients/client.jpg'>]]></ClientLogo>
<ClientName>Client Example</ClientName>
<category>Support</category>
<CategoryLink>client-categories</CategoryLink>
</Person>
```

With a tiny bit of tweeking I will be able to remove all the '![CDATA[<' from the logos in the XML too

Answer (score 1):

`""'>"` should be `"'>"`. That's why you're getting the exception, it's not a valid string.

More generally, I'd favour sending the uri and the content as separate items (the uri as an attribute itself), or defining the XML to allow for `<a>` elements directly in the content. Escaping XML or HTML to put into XML works, but can lead to nastiness if you end up escaping that XML to put into some XML, which you then escape to...

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer Jon. The problem is I think I need that extra " to put the clientname in the link so it can be generated like: category-list.aspx?cat=clientname. Would you agree? Sorry I am very new to the world of C# I wouldnt know how to send them as separate items.

Comment: I'm not sure what you need to do, but it certainly isn't that. Presumably `person.ClientName` contains the likes of "Example Client", so what contains `exampleClient`? Does that come from mangling the name, or somewhere else?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction Jon, I worked out the answer which will be below